# What's the meaning of "the form of the question" here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, legalese

> A: You're, um your husband's death?
>
> B: Yes.
>
> A: Dating again?
>
> C: Objection. This certainly has no relevance.
>
> A: All objections have been waived till the trial, **except for the form
>   of the question**, sport. This your first deposition?
>
> C: This is not my first deposition.
>
> A: Well, then play by the rules. Don't make me move for costs, which
>   she'll end up paying.

From Boston Legal Season 1 Episode 2

What does "the form of the question" mean in this dialogue or context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a witness is examined during a deposition or a trial, there are restrictions on which questions can be asked by the lawyers. If the other side feels that those restrictions aren't met, they can object to the question. [Here](http://www.illinoistrialpractice.com/2009/07/objections-to-the-form-of-a-question-a-partial-list.html) is a list of common objections to *the form of a question*; a question could be too vague, or already answered before. <sub>(Why does this remind me of the close vote review queue?)</sub> You see that the reasons are quite diverse; they don't have a common denominator. In the end, these restrictions are all necessary to guarantee a fair and objective testimony.